# Incorporating external script into Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm incorporating an external theme into Meteor. It has some scripts loaded before the end of the body tag. The `<script>` tags doesn't work when inside the `<body>` of the Meteor template.

The theme uses js like Bootstrap, jquery, and various other probably external JS libraries (which it also puts at the end, before the `</body>`. The last script is this `custom.js` script which is this theme-specific. Inside the script other than regular functions statements, there are two anonymous functions, two `if` blocks at the top level, a `$(document).ready` callback and a `$(window).load` callback.

What's the best way to load the scripts with the least tempering? I tried to move all the scripts inside the `<head>` of the Meteor template. But some effects is missing. I think maybe the `$(window).load` is not getting called at the right time. So I call it inside `Template.scriptAppend.rendered` where scriptAppend is a template to a partial right before the end of the `</body>`. I also move the two anonymous functions and the two `if` blocks inside the `$(window).load`. It works but it's such a hassle. Is there a way to leave the script as it is?

Before all these I initially just think I would use jQuery to add the `<script>` tags in inside `Template.scriptAppend.rendered` but there seems to be no effect and I have no idea why.

So my questions are, (1) is there a way to leave the script as it is and (2) when is Meteor `<head>` get processed anyway? Apparently `$(window).load` is not getting executed at the right time expected by the script.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Meteor loads files in a different order than a normal web server, meaning that your functions won't load as you're used to. Including the external script in the head is just fine, but you should try placing everything that would normally go inside the `$(document).ready()` function inside a `Template.templatename.rendered` function instead. That has done the trick for me in the past.