# Meteor loading external scripts conditionally

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to make a multi-page Meteor app (I'm using https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router). How do I conditionally load javascripts depending on the page content?

This is what I'm doing: the main page `main.html` has a {{renderPage}} within the `<body>` tag which is what the Meteor-router use. Say there is this page/template called `home` which is one of the pages and it has some of it's scripts.  If it were not for Meteor some of these scripts are in `<header>` such as jquery, while others are at the end of `<body>`. I put a partial at the end of the `home` template called `homeCustomScripts` and it has a corresponding Template.homeCustomScripts function like so (I left-out many scripts, this is just an example):

```
Template.homeCustomScripts.created = function() {
  scriptInsert = function () {
    $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="js-plugin/respond/respond.min.js">`
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js-plugin/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>`
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>');

  }
}
```

Within `main.html` I have another partial called customScript and I have inside `Template.customScript.rendered` calls `scriptInsert()`.

It should work, except that there are some really messy Javascript error at the Chrome console which I've no idea what it means:

[image]

I'm guessing that because Meteor also loads JQuery in `<head>` and I heard that Meteor is loading everything in there last, so maybe the JQuery plugin easing is loaded before that instance of JQuery.
But I don't know.

What's the best way to load different script for different page in a multi-page application in Meteor?

Comment: Check this: http://empire5.com/development/meteor-using-iron-router-to-conditionally-load-javascript-libraries/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is loading the scripts multiple times - each time the template is rendered (this almost always happens many times even for simple pages) - you are injecting the same code over and over which is likely causing the errors

---

i'm not sure i would engage in this patten - based on how meteor works even with multi-page apps using meteor-router (the page never reloads) you should just include your javascript files in your app directory and have them already loaded via 1 combined and minified javascript file - you may need to place your files in the `client/compatibility` directory to circumvent any scoping issues see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/History.md

if your files are truly already inside your app directory, they are already loaded and this is not needed at all - by default meteor will load and serve everything to the browser in any directory except `server` or `tests`

---

this could make a little more sense if you were loading external scripts, in which case you should use the router filters to accomplish this

```
Meteor.Router.filters({
  'isCustomScriptLoaded': function(page) {
    if(!Session.equals('isCustomScriptLoaded', true)){
        Session.set('isCustomScriptLoaded', true);
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.async = true;
        script.src = "<EXTERNAL SCRIPT URL>";

        var firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(script, firstScript);
    }
  }
});

Meteor.Router.filter('isCustomScriptLoaded',{only: ['pageThatNeedsCustomScript'] });
```

that would load the script as needed and keep it loaded - you want to only load it once, not each time the page is loaded or even worse rendered

loading scripts in this way may still be problematic - if the page renders for the last time before the script is loaded it might not work correctly - your best bet is to include all needed files right away

Comment: Why is it loading multiple times? Putting alert in callbacks shows they're called once.

Comment: By external I mean scripts which I obtained from a purchased theme. I put all scripts and CSSes in `public`, but the Javascripts loading order matters with the original scripts. (My previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851395/incorporating-external-script-into-meteor). Say some DOM elements within a different page requires a different third-party scripts. Although the page never reloads, that new element is brought into the page by a click to this "new page", and some script should be included with that page.

Comment: And I don't want everything to load at once because I fear it would not be pretty. Maybe Meteor is not that suitable for this type of usage at this point? It's my first ever real web project I tried to do and I picked Meteor to try it out.

Comment: `rendered()` will get called multiple times on almost any template - your code definitely appears to be attempting to load multiple times

Comment: `Javascripts loading order matters with the original scripts` - rename the files as needed to make them load as needed (meteor loads in a-z order, so 1-thisFirst.js, 2-thenThisSecond.js, etc)

`load at once because I fear it would not be pretty` this is not a valid concern - you actually want as few files as possible sent from server to client to be as speedy as possible - i assure you meteor is suitable nearly any type of web application - you just need to adjust your thinking to the meteor way and everything will be fine

Comment: You mean to send all scripts at once is better than loading as per needed bases depending on which page the user access? (provided that scripts already loaded is not reloaded again) Wouldn't that increase the up-front wait when user is accessing the site?

Comment: its a trade off - slightly slower up front loading time gives you zero loading time when navigating within the app - this is the preferred meteor way - most apps/frameworks that dont cause page reloads (aka single page) load everything all up front - i've built several apps this way with no complaints