# Conditionally load internal assets in Meteor

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to prevent automatic loading of all assets in my /client folder?

I am looking at a scenario where my login page uses different css/js files than my registration or view users folders. What is the best way to do this?

The closest I have come to a solution is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896289/meteor-loading-external-scripts-conditionally) but that still doesn't solve my problem.

Or the best approach is to host my files externally then user the [external-file-loader](https://atmospherejs.com/package/external-file-loader) with conditional statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just published `modules` smart package which more or less does the job for you. You can add it to your project with

```
mrt add modules
```

Then, you will need to change the extensions of all files that you want to load asynchronously to `.module_js` or `.module_html` (currentlly we do not support `css`). Now suppose that the structure of your directory is more or less

```
modules
  module1
    file1.module_js
    file2.module_js
  module2
    file1.module_js
    file2.module_js
client
  main.js
server
public
...
```

Initially only `main.js` will be present in your application. To load additional code for the client use the asynchronous `require` call:

```
require('module1', function () {
  console.log('the files contained in module1 folder are now loaded');
});
```

Comment: Seems to be what I am looking for, will check the module for updates (css). Github link?

Comment: You can have a look on the repo [here](https://github.com/anticoders/meteor-modules) and you can also easily find it on the [atmosphere](https://atmospherejs.com/).